# Finding the replacement of the SOAP APIs for WSO2 identity server for 6.0.0 version for challenge Question API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

1.Under Challenge Questions API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/
, we are using /{user-id}​/challenge-answers(GET) and ​/{user-id}​/challenge-answers(PUT) API.
Is there any way we can pass email-id instead of userID.

2.Under Challenge Questions API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/, we are using /me/challenges(GET) is there any way we can retrieve local challenge question claim.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Under Challenge Questions API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/ , we are using /{user-id}​/challenge-answers(GET) and ​/{user-id}​/challenge-answers(PUT) API. Is there any way we can pass email-id instead of userID.

The API requires a unique identifier. Sending the email id will not work. The way you need to implement is retrieve the user first and get the UUID (unique identifier) and use it with the APIs.

> 2.Under Challenge Questions API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/, we are using /me/challenges(GET) is there any way we can retrieve local challenge question claim.

I believe here you are referring to answers to the challenge questions. To get them use this [/me/challenge-answers](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/me/getAnsweredChallengesOfLoggedInUser).